# Are reference non-type template parameters deduced by decltype(auto) forwardable in case of template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, template-templates

Yet another `decltype(auto)` template *template-parameter* question. This time minimal code I was able to create to reproduce the error looks like this:

```
template <template <decltype(auto)> class TT, decltype(auto) V>
void foo(TT<V>) {
};

template <decltype(auto)>
struct Bar{};

int x;

int main() {
    foo(Bar<(x)>{});
}
```

This in [[clang]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VSbNzcgxE7KCWnvw) results in:

```
prog.cc:11:5: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
    foo(Bar<(x)>{});
    ^~~
prog.cc:2:6: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with TT = Bar]: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
void foo(TT<V>) {
     ^
1 error generated.
```

[[gcc]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3jeDfwTpWDLLMqO7) accepts the code.

To my understanding the code is well-formed and clang is buggy in its interpretation, but need the confirmation before submitting a bug to lvvm. Am I right?

Comment: @StoryTeller I get your point. I'll try to edit the question to be less suggestive when get back to computer

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't understand your comment. `TT` is a template template-parameter, that deduces to `Bar` just fine? clang's problem is in deducing `V`

Comment: @Barry - My comment was about the mcve. I can swear TT was a plain `decltype(auto)`. Not a template. Appearantly I just misread.

Comment: Anyway, I'm not by a computer, but I too would be really surprised if this isn't officially well-formed.

Comment: Simpler example: have `foo` just be `template <decltype(auto) V> void foo(Bar<V> ) { }` - same behavior, just one less variable

Comment: @Barry: I think that pretty much solidifies it as a clang bug, yeah?

Comment: I'll try to find appropriate standard fragment and get back with filed bug, not sure if I will be able do it today. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to error clang does not have a problem with deducing template *template-parameter* which is also standard compliant - [[temp.arg.template]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.template#3) (empasis mine):

> **A template-argument matches a template template-parameter P when P is
>   at least as specialized as the template-argument A**. If P contains a
>   parameter pack, then A also matches P if each of A's template
>   parameters matches the corresponding template parameter in the
>   template-parameter-list of P. **Two template parameters match if they
>   are of the same kind (type, non-type, template), for non-type
>   template-parameters, their types are equivalent ([temp.over.link])**,
>   and for template template-parameters, each of their corresponding
>   template-parameters matches, recursively. When P's
>   template-parameter-list contains a template parameter pack, the
>   template parameter pack will match zero or more template parameters or
>   template parameter packs in the template-parameter-list of A with the
>   same type and form as the template parameter pack in P (ignoring
>   whether those template parameters are template parameter packs)

Now lets make sure the `Bar<(x)>{}` should be deduced as reference. This is covered by [[dcl.type.auto.deduct]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.auto.deduct#5) and [[dcl.type.simple]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#4).

Finally lets check if we actually can use the reference to the variable with linkage as a template argument [[temp.arg.nontype]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#2):

> A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a
>   converted constant expression of the type of the template-parameter.
>   **For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, the
>   value of the constant expression shall not refer to (or for a pointer
>   type, shall not be the address of)**:
>
> - **a subobject,**
> - **a temporary object,**
> - **a string literal,**
> - **the result of a typeid expression, or**
> - **a predefined *­*­func_­_­ variable.**
>
> [ Note: If the template-argument represents a set of overloaded
>   functions (or a pointer or member pointer to such), the matching
>   function is selected from the set ([over.over]). — end note  ]

The deduced argument fulfils the requirements. This makes the code well-formed and suggests clang's bug.

[Filed bug 34690](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34690)